# Migration from PowerShell 5 to 7: can't load types from System.ServiceModel.Web v4.0.0.0

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-7.0

Recently transitioned from PowerShell 5.1 to 7.3.6. Most scripts are fine, but there is one puzzling issue with a script calling a .NET class.

The class can't load, crashing with this message:

```
System.Management.Automation.ExtendedTypeSystemException: The following exception occurred while retrieving member "Parse": "Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvokeAttribute' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'."
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvokeAttribute' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(QCallModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctorWithParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.MethodCacheEntry.get_IsHidden()
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.GetDotNetMethodImpl[T](Object obj, String methodName, MemberNamePredicate predicate)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.GetDotNetMethod[T](Object obj, String methodName)
   at System.Management.Automation.Adapter.BaseGetMember[T](Object obj, String memberName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

`Add-Type` doesn't help.

Interestingly enough, the very same script runs just fine in a neighboring tab with PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: Powershell 6+ is built on top of .net core. If the classes are in .net and not .net core, you'll need to keep using 5.1. Powershell 6+ is not a complete replacement of 5.1 and there is no requirement to move scripts to Powershell 6+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System.ServiceModel.Web** is not supported on .NET Core. Every new release of PowerShell since 6 is built on a newer version of .NET Core, so classes from .NET Framework will not work in them. You can find out more about the differences between versions 5.1 and later [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.3).

Comment: I see, thank you. I guess we'll need to upgrade these classes, too.